# I'm getting a 404 NOT_FOUND CODE: 'DEPLOYMENT NOT FOUND on wordpress multisite installation on my sub domain

Tags: multisite, 404-error, wp-config

I Installed multisite on localhost installation of wordpress. After installation it gave me the below code snippet to add in wp-config.php file:

define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'www.example.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );

My home and siteurl are :

define('WP_HOME','http://www.example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.example.com');

After installation I reloaded my nginx server and visited my website. It is redirecting me to:
http://www.www.example.com and it gives 404:NOT_FOUND

[image]

Comment: What gave you the snippet? A re you using a particular application for installing WordPress locally?

Comment: I got the snippet from wordpress dashboard after enabling the network setup by adding define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true); and installing then it showed me the snippet and isntructed to paste that in wp-config.php